# Jenkins: change top level environment variable

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I set environment variable at top level of declarative pipeline with `agent none` defined.
How can i change it value inside stages with docker agents?
I need to keep changed values persistent among agents.

Comment: Can you post a bit of code from your pipeline?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tested the code below and it worked. Running it in Docker shouldn't have any impact. The top-level "agent none" also shouldn't have any impact, if it does, just define a very small agent, resource-wise at the top level.

```
# Define the variable and set it to some value.
myVar = 12
# A function to use in the environment blocks below.
def getVar() {
    return myVar
}
pipeline {
    agent any
    environment {
        # Set the environment variable to the value of the Groovy variable.
        MY_VAR = getVar()
    }
    stages {
        stage("Test1") {
            steps {
                script {
                    # Change the value of the Groovy variable.
                    myVar = 13
                }
                # The environment variable won't change as long as we don't use an environment block to change it.
                sh "echo ${MY_VAR}"
            }
        }
        stage("Test2") {
            environment {
                # Updating the environment variable.
                MY_VAR = getVar()
            }
            steps {
                # And checking that it has been updated.
                sh "echo ${MY_VAR}"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For me this prints:

```
+ echo 12
12
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Test2)
[Pipeline] withEnv
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] sh
[Pipeline__all-branches__CI] Running shell script
+ echo 13
13
```

So the variable value persists between stages and you can change it in any stage.

Comment: Thank you, @oblio.
Maybe i described  problem not full enough.
"How can i change it value inside stages with **different** docker agents?"

Comment: Thank you, @oblio.
Maybe i described  problem not full enough.
"How can i change it value inside stages with **different** docker agents?"
I used `agent none` at the top because it is necessary when there are several different agents at different stages.
I can redefine env variable at stage level, but all changes lost when i go to the next stage with new agent.

Comment: The agents don't matter. The Groovy variable I defined at the top is persistent, it's available in all stages and steps, regardless if they're Docker on not.

Comment: Just try the thing I did, with the Groovy variable, the Groovy function that gets its value and with the environment block that calls the Groovy function to set the environment variable value.

Comment: Thank you @oblio 
i was little bit confuse about Groovy and Env variables. now it clear.